# Passing Pointers to Functions?

Tags: c++, pointers

```
#include <iostream>

void swap (int *a, int *b) {
    int *k = a;
    a = b;
    b = k;
}

int main() {
    int alpha = 5;
    int beta = 34;

    swap (alpha,beta);

    std::cout << alpha << std::endl;
    std::cout << beta << std::endl;

    int *ab = new int();
    *ab = 34;
    int *cd = new int();
    *cd =64;

    swap(ab,cd);

    std::cout << *ab << std::endl;
    std::cout << *cd << std::endl;
}
```

First Question: How am I able to pass values to a function which has pointers as passing parameters.

Second Question: How is it able to swap. It swaps the pointers. But when it comes out shouldn't the values of alpha and beta still remain same.

Third Question: Why doesn't the function work when I pass pointers but works when I pass regular variables.

Fourth Question: In the function     `void swap(int *a, int* b)` are `int *a` and `int *b` references?

Comment: Your `using namespace std;` is messing you up. The standard swap function is actually implemented correctly. Yours is not.

Comment: `swap (&alpha,&beta);`

Comment: @chris Actually, in the first call he accidentally uses `std::swap`, :).

Comment: The close votes are needlessly hostile. This is a legitimate question.

Comment: @40two, Which is why it works.

Answer (score 4):

And that would serve the best examples for why we should not include namespace std at global level…

```
swap (alpha,beta);
```

would call `std::swap` rather than your own `swap`.

> Third Question: Why doesn't the function work when I pass pointers but works when I pass regular variables

Because your `swap` isn't properly written. It should be:

```
void swap (int *a, int *b) {
    // Preferably you should also check if pointers are not NULL.
    int temp;
    temp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = temp;
}
```

> Fourth Question: In the function `void swap(int *a, int* b)` are `int *a` and `int *b` references?

The syntax of reference is:

```
void swap ( int& a, int& b );
```

So no, they aren't. They are pointers.

Answer (score 1):

First of all your swap function is wrong. I suppose you want to swap not pointers themselves but the objects pointed to by the pointers. It should be defined as

```
void swap ( int *a, int *b ) 
{
    int k = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = k;
}
```

and it can be called like

```
swap ( &alpha, &beta );
```

and

```
swap( ab, cd );
```

In this function parameters a and b are pointers. If you want to use references as the parameters then the function will look like

```
void swap( int &a, int &b )
{
   int tmp = a;
   a = b;
   b = tmp;
}
```

and can be called like

```
swap ( alpha, beta );
```

and

```
swap( *ab, *cd );
```

If you want to swap separatly pointers and objects pointed to by pointers then either you need to define two overloaded functions or one template function like standard C++ function `std::swap`.

Comment: It is giving a compilation error when I use     int k. When I use     int *k, it gives no problem.

Comment: Integers cannot be assigned pointers.

Comment: @John. J. Adams  There was a typo. See the updated post.

Comment: @rightføld  You are right.